# Select Worksheet using the prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select a worksheet in my activeworkbook and there is only one and   it starts with EXP, how do i do that, I am trying something like below.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EXP*").Select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop and find:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If (sheet.Name Like "EXP*") Then
        sheet.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can I not do it without looping? Something similar to what I have stated above

Comment: That functionality is not supported by the Collection that contains the WorkSheets

Comment: If you do this a lot, put it inside a function

Comment: The only way to avoid a loop would be if you know it always had the same position in the workbook--that it is always the first or second, etc. worksheet. Then you would refer to it by Worksheets(index). Even then, I'd be reluctant to trust it in a production environment